# Extracting georeferenced GIS raster data as a function of coordinates

Tags: geographics, geodesy

When importing geospatial raster files, the coordinates seem to be lost, if I am not mistaken. I am not sure how to get the values of raster based on the coordinates (in whatever projection the raster has been assigned). Let say this example dataset:

```
Import[ "ExampleData/cea.tif", "GeoTIFF"]
```

This command only imports the image file. If I use "Data":

```
Import[ "ExampleData/cea.tif", "Data"]
```

The cell values are imported, but not georeferenced:

> {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<450>>,99,90,99,132,148,140,173,132,181,148,165,123,115,99,140,140,140,132,132,123,107,156,173,123,115,82,165,222,115,82,0,0},<<514>>}

Is there a way to get this done? In other words, is it possible to get MMA recognized "GeoPositions" from raster data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the GeoTIFF importer is somewhat lacking and doesn't really reflect what people often end up doing with GeoTIFFs these days.

In any case, here's a functional but somewhat poorly written method to do what you're looking for.

First, we want to get the projection from the geotiff. We need this, because a geotiff is necessarily gridded, and we will want to convert back from this gridded projection.

```
proj = Import[ 
   "ExampleData/cea.tif", {"GeoTIFF", "Projection"}] /. {None -> 0}
```

> ```
> {"CylindricalEqualArea", "Centering" -> {0, -117.333}, 
>  "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, "StandardParallels" -> {33.75, 0}, 
>  "ReferenceModel" -> {Quantity[6.35658*10^6, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[6.37821*10^6, "Meters"]}}
> ```

`None` must be replaced by `0` in order to pass this to `GeoGridPosition` later on. We also need to fudge our `"ReferenceModel"` into a single radius rather than a semimajor and semiminor axis - I'm really not sure why this is the case, but GeoGridPosition doesn't seem to like it. I suspect it's either a bug, or I don't know what I'm doing. In any case, we do this like so:

```
proj = proj /. ("ReferenceModel" -> x_) :> "ReferenceModel" -> Mean@x
```

Now, let's get the image data and spatial range:

```
{imgd, range} = Import[ "ExampleData/cea.tif", {"GeoTIFF", {"Data", "SpatialRange}}]
```

In the case of the example tiff, the spatial range is expressed in metres - it is possible that any arbitrary tiff will express this in feet, kilometres, miles, or barleycorns. You can check what the range unit is by importing the `"LinearUnits"` element.

What we have now is the distance between the left and right side of the image in metres, and the same for the bottom and top side of the image. Since our image is gridded, we can simply count the number of rows and columns and get the distance between each pixel in the grid by dividing the range between left and right and up and down, and the row and column count. In other GeoTIFFs you may be able to get this via the `"SpatialResolution"` import element.

```
{rows, cols} = Dimensions@imgd

{rd, cd} = Differences /@ range

{rd, cd}/{rows, cols}
```

In this case, we get a pixel resolution of just over 60 metres by 60 metres per pixel, which sounds about right.

Now we'll generate the X and Y of each cell in the rows and columns.

```
rds = range[[1, 1]] + Flatten@Accumulate[Table[rd/rows, rows]] + rd / 2;
cds = range[[2, 1]] + Flatten@Accumulate[Table[cd/cols, cols]];
```

and then map through our image data, creating a `GeoGridPosition` of the X and Y of the grid. (Side note - I don't know why we need to add half the Y here.)

```
data = MapIndexed[
    GeoGridPosition[{cds[[#2[[2]]]], rds[[#2[[1]]]]}, proj] -> #1 &, 
    imgd, {2}] // Flatten;
```

Now, if we get say the 20th element, we will get a `GeoGridPosition` and a value:

```
data[[20]]
```

> ```
> GeoGridPosition[{-27292.7, 4.22503*10^6}, {"CylindricalEqualArea", 
>    "Centering" -> {0, -117.333}, "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, 
>    "StandardParallels" -> {33.75, 0}, 
>    "ReferenceModel" -> Quantity[6.3674*10^6, "Meters"]}] -> 165
> ```

Now let's convert into GeoPositions and view a resampled version of our data:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 MapAt[GeoPosition, data[[;; ;; Round[(Length@data/10000)]]], {All, 1}],
 GeoBackground -> None,
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel
]
```

[image]

Comparing with the actual image:

[image]

If we overlay this on a satellite image, we can see that the output lines up with the satellite data in the background. It's a little hard to see in the image here - try it out yourself and vary the opacity.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 MapAt[GeoPosition, data[[;; ;; Round[(Length@data/5000)]]], {All, 1}],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
 GeoBackground -> "Satellite"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I get the remapping part but how do you guys come up with the other stuff such as None vs. 0 or SpatialRange?! That's way over my head.. Are you aware of any other raster formats that can be mapped easier or they all have this problem? I think it might be much easier to convert them externally