# Combining ReliefPlots with GeoGraphics/Converting ReliefPlots into GeoGraphics

Tags: plotting, geography, geographics, projection

I want to use [.DEM files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/USGSDEM.html) with `GeoGraphics[]`. For example, adding labels, or changing projections.

In my attempt, I import the example data from Wolfram.

```
Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "ColorFunction" -> "DarkTerrain"]
data = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "Data"]
projection = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "Projection"]
spatialrange = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "SpatialRange"]
```

[image]

Adapted from this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264169/extracting-georeferenced-gis-raster-data-as-a-function-of-coordinates), I generate the spacing of each pixel,

```
{rows, cols} = Dimensions@data
{rd, cd} = Differences /@ spatialrange
{rd, cd}/{rows, cols}
rds = spatialrange[[1, 1]] + Flatten@Accumulate[Table[rd/rows, rows]] + rd[[1]]/2;
cds = spatialrange[[2, 1]] + Flatten@Accumulate[Table[cd/cols, cols]];
```

I now try to convert this to geodata.

```
geodata = MapIndexed[GeoGridPosition[{cds[[#2[[2]]]], rds[[#2[[1]]]]}, projection] -> #1 &, data, {2}] // Flatten;
```

Which fails with invalid projection specifications:

```
GeoGridPosition::invproj: Invalid projection specification {None, "ReferenceModel" -> {Quantity[6.3565838*^6, "Meters"], Quantity[6.3782064*^6, "Meters"]}}.
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? Why is the projection not valid?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is

```
geodata=MapIndexed[GeoGridPosition[{QuantityMagnitude[cds[[#2[[2]]]]],QuantityMagnitude[rds[[#2[[1]]]]]},{"Mercator","ReferenceModel"->{6378137,6378137}}]->#1&,data,{2}]//Flatten;
```

Which can be combined with GeoGraphics

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[MapAt[GeoPosition,geodata[[;;;;100]],{All,1}],GeoBackground->None,ColorFunction->GrayLevel]
```

and

[image]

It is very slow and not elegant. I might of been better creating some graphic that is stretched etc.